# Scale fill gradient using absolute values

Tags: r, ggplot2

In the following chart, I would like a gradient to be applied at an absolute value level, rather than relative values. For example, rows I and G should be the same color of red as their values are -75 and 75, respectively. By the same token, rows F and E should be the same shade of green as their values are -15 and 15, respectively. Can anyone tell me how I would do this?

[image]

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

data.frame(grp = LETTERS[1:10],
           vals = c(0.11,  0.39, -0.06,  0.42,  0.15, -0.15,  0.75, -0.02,  -0.75,  0.00)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = vals, y = grp, fill = vals)) +
  geom_col() +
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "green", high = "red")
```

Comment: Try with `fill = abs(vals)`

Answer (score 3):

You could simply use `fill = abs(vals)`

```
data.frame(grp = LETTERS[1:10],
           vals = c(0.11,  0.39, -0.06,  0.42,  0.15, -0.15,  0.75, -0.02,  -0.75,  0.00)) %>% 
        ggplot(aes(x = vals, y = grp, fill = abs(vals))) +
        geom_col() +
        scale_fill_gradient(low = "green", high = "red")
```

[image]